# What is the difference between "prononco" and "elparolo"?

Tags: word-usage

I first learned the word ***prononco*** for *pronunciation*.  When I first started reading PMEG a couple of months ago, I noticed the word ***elparolo*** is used.

What is the difference between the two words? When would I use the one over the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used PIV and found these definitions:

prononco

Maniero kiel oni prononcas

There was no result for elparolo, but I imagine it would be something like: "Maniero kiel oni elparolas". Hence, it becomes a matter of verbs instead of nouns:

prononco

Artikige aŭdigi

elparoli

1 Prononci

2 Elfluigi la vortojn en propra maniero

It seems like they are synonyms. I'd say that this is another example where Esperanto has two words for the same thing: one loaned root and one kunmetaĵo, alike hospitalo and malsanulejo.

Answer (score 2):

According to my research, *elparolo* is closer to *enunciation* and *prononco* to *pronunciation*, whose difference in English itself is delicate.